# Find source of light reflecting from surface of sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometric-optics

Suppose we have a reflective sphere of known radius, `r`, in the center of a hemispherical-dome of LED lights of an infinite radius. If we are looking down upon the sphere from the center of the dome then it will appear to be a circle, with points of light reflecting from the LEDs.

*Top image: Side view of dome and reflective sphere; Bottom image: Top down view of sphere as it appears to the observer in the center of the dome.*

[image: Top image: Side view of dome and reflective sphere; Bottom image: Top down view of sphere as it appears to the observer in the center of the dome.]

How can we determine the position of the LEDs from the light reflected from the sphere i.e. from an image of it as it appears to be a circle?

It is easy enough to construct a vector from the center of the reflective sphere to the point of light on its surface (green vector), but this won't be a vector in the direction of the LED will it?

Any help appreciated; I'll post this in maths if it's better off there?

> Edit: *Okay, so all light received by the observer will arrive
>   perpendicular to the normal vector running from the centre of the
>   sphere up towards the observer, that makes sense. The angle between
>   the vector normal to the tangent of the sphere where the light hit and
>   the light arriving at the observer is the same as the angle between
>   the vector normal to the tangent of the sphere where the light hit and
>   the angle at which the light arrived from the dome. I still don't
>   understand how I can work out a vector from the origin to that initial
>   LED, anything obvious that I'm missing?*

Comment: Please show your effort to solve this problem. We do not do calculations for you. The only physics here is the law of reflection. The mathematics is more difficult (3D geometry). The question you are asking (about vector geometry) might be better on Mathematics SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observer does not see a circle of light from each LED; he/she only sees a single point image of the point object (the LED). The observer, the point image, the centre of the sphere, and the point object (LED) all lie in the same plane.
[image]
Use spherical co-ordinates. The observer looks down on the inner sphere and sees a plane circle (*left diagram*). He/she chooses any direction to be North (N) and measures the angle $\phi$ between the lines ON and OI, where O is the centre of the inner sphere (also the dome) and I is the image point in the sphere. The object point L (the LED) lies on the dome in the same plane as points O, I and the observer O'.

The observer also measures the angle A subtended by the line OI (*right diagram*). This angle can be related by geometry to the angle C between the lines OO' and OI, and the radii $R, r$ of the outer dome and inner sphere :
$\cot A \sin C +\cos C=\frac{R}{r}$.
Solving for C gives the angle $\theta=2C$ between OO' and OL.

The position of the LED on the dome is then $(\theta,\phi)$ measured from the centre O. The position of the observer O' is $(\theta, \phi)=(0,0)$.

**Note** : If the LED emits light in all directions then the observer will be able to see the LED directly, without the aid of the reflection from the inner sphere, and could more easily locate it by measuring the angles directly to the LED.

Answer (score 0):

Because the dome has an infinite radius, the angle at which the light arrives at or leaves the sphere is directly related to the position on the dome where the light was emitted or received and is independent of the position on the sphere.

For example all the light received by the observer at the top of the dome leaves the sphere vertically. In the drawing, the light reaching the top of the dome is drawn at an nonzero angle with the vertical axis. When the radius of the dome is truly infinite, this angle will be zero.

It then becomes easy to calculate the relation between the position on the sphere and the position on the dome.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a play and see if I can get it before marking your answer as solved :)

Comment: Okay, so all light received by the observer will arrive perpendicular to the normal vector running from the centre of the sphere up towards the observer, that makes sense.

The angle between the vector normal to the tangent of the sphere where the light hit and the light arriving at the observer is the same as the angle between the vector normal to the tangent of the sphere where the light hit and the angle at which the light arrived from the dome.

I still don't understand how I can work out a vector from the origin to that initial LED, anything obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Is it to do with [this](http://i.imgur.com/q03IUZq.jpg) angle relation?